# How to unverified a verified number in firebase phone authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

Is there a way to unverified a verified number in firebase account (phone authentication)?

There is more than two days I am trying to find a way to resend SMS code, in `react-native-firebase` but unfortunately I couldn't find a solution for that.

Now I think if I unverify a number or unauthenticate a number I maybe able send the SMS code again.

because as I tested firebase **only send SMS code to unverified or unauthenticate number**

Comment: What do you mean unverify? Do you want to remove that user's phone number from the account? Why do you want to do this? Phone numbers are not recycled that often.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to set the phone number of a user account to unverified within the Firebase Authentication API. You may want to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for this.

Re-sending the verification code definitely isn't going to result in the account becoming unverified.

Comment: Hello Mr Frank, Could you please show me a way to resend sms code?

Comment: As far as I know calling `signInWithPhoneNumber` should send an SMS. There might be quota on it though, so you may have to wait.

Comment: Hello Mr Frank thank you to help,
Now I find a way, to resend the code and it using `verifyPhoneNumber(phone)` function instead of using `signInWithPhoneNumber(phone)`. using `verifyPhoneNumber` helped me to resend the code.
But I faced with another problem, and it is confirming the code.
with `signInWithPhoneNumber` we have a `confirmResult`, which we can confrm the code.
But now how to **confirm** a received code with `verifyPhoneNumber`?

Comment: You call `signInWithPhoneNumber` and then `confirmationResult.confirm(code)` in its callback, with the code you got from `verifyPhoneNumber`. Note that this point I'm simply reading sections of the documentation to you https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#sign-in-the-user-with-the-verification-code. If you're having specific problems implementing the docs, it's much easier to help if you add the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question.

Comment: Hello Mr Frank thank you very much,
I mean now I am just using `verifyPhoneNumber ` instead of `signInWithPhoneNumber`, could you please help me here how to confirm the sms code we received?.
I didnt find any in doc